# How to calculate how long a device can run on a battery, prior to the battery depleting past a certain point?

Tags: battery-charging

I've got a car battery with the following spec: Voltage: 12V; Battery capacity (C20): 95Ah. Full spec [here](https://www.batterymegastore.co.uk/product/type-019-bosch-s4013-car-battery-12v-95ah/)

I want to power a dash cam from the car battery, the dash cam is to run constantly whether the engine is on or off.

The dash cam draws the following: c. 4.9 V, 0.35 A

The engine won't start when the car battery is below 12.5 V.

If the battery was fully charged and in prime condition, how long could the dash cam run before the battery was at 12.5 V?

Comment: Several possible duplicates: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/217860/2028, https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/155723/2028, https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/340741/2028, https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/93718/2028, etc.

Comment: You would have to know what is the voltage from which the battery starts to discharge, and how the voltage drops during discharge, before it reaches 12.5V. Likely not linear. So with the given information, it can't be calculated.

Comment: This looks like a fake battery and  the datasheet link work  nor on Archive.org  Look up Peukert's Law  and these batteries https://www.tayna.co.uk/docs/catalogues/bosch/bosch-brochure-2014.pdf